# Self-referential function in Haskell (interleaveStreams)

Tags: haskell

My code caused some sort of infinite recursion so I decided to look through this post (OP was doing the same problem as me: implementing the ruler function on an infinite Stream):

[Implementing the ruler function using `streamInterleave`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330709/implementing-the-ruler-function-using-streaminterleave)

My code looked like this:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
streamRepeat x = Cons x (streamRepeat x)

interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons x (Cons y (streamInterleave xs ys))

ruler :: Stream Integer
ruler = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) (streamMap (+1) $ ruler)
```

Now, it turns out that if I change the definition of interleaveStreams to

```
interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (interleaveStreams ys xs)
```

and leave everything else as is, there is no infinite recursion and it works properly. As far as I know, the two versions of interleaveStreams are equivalent. Why does one of them hang, while the other one works properly?

Comment: An aside: `streamRepeat x = let r = Cons x r in r`, or `streamRepeat x = fix (Cons x)`, is better because it produces a *cyclical* structure instead of one that grows without bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you need only the head of `Cons x (Cons y (streamInterleave xs ys))`. The hanging implementation of `interleaveStreams` still says it needs to match both `Cons x xs` and `Cons y ys` to do that. This is enough to break some operations you’d probably like to be valid, when the value that matches `Cons y ys` is a function of `x`.

That’s the case for `ruler = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) (streamMap (+1) $ ruler)`! To simplify, `streamMap` doesn’t change anything about this:

```
ruler = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) ruler
```

and ignoring `streamRepeat`:

```
interleaveStreams (Cons y ys) = Cons 0 (Cons y (streamInterleave xs ys))
ruler = interleaveStreams ruler
```

you can see why Haskell can’t figure out what `y` is.

Another option is to use a lazy pattern:

```
interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) ~(Cons y ys) = Cons x (Cons y (streamInterleave xs ys))
```

Or you could give `ruler` a head start:

```
ruler = Cons 0 (interleaveStreams (streamMap (+1) ruler) (streamRepeat 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the body of `interleaveStreams` can be evaluated, both parameters need to be destructured.

But when you call `interleaveStreams` from `ruler`, the second parameter is `ruler` itself.

And so it turns out that before the body of `interleaveStreams` can be evaluated, `ruler` needs to be evaluated at least partially, at least enough to be destructured.

But the whole body of `ruler` is a call to `interleaveStreams`, so `ruler` cannot be evaluated until `interleaveStreams` is evaluated. That's your infinite loop.

In the alternative definition of `interleaveStreams`, you produce a `Cons` result without needing to destructure the second parameter, so evaluation can proceed.